# counting how many outputs are greater than 0.5 in a binary classification problem

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the following code after the  optimizer I want to count that in each batch how many samples are there whose labels are greater than 0.5. While preparing data I assign the labels 0 and 1 to the training set. Can someone please tell me how to do that? I am using mini batch method for training

```
logits = tf.matmul(pool_2D, W_fc)   #(batch_size,2)
y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(logits)

#Calculate_loss_and apply_Back_propagation:
cross_entropy = 
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=y_)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.rLearn).minimize(loss) `
```

Where x and y placeholders are

```
`x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, FLAGS.image_height*FLAGS.image_width])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

input = tf.reshape(x, [-1, FLAGS.image_height, FLAGS.image_width, 
FLAGS.input_channel])
filter = weight_variable([FLAGS.filter_size, FLAGS.filter_size, 
FLAGS.input_channel, FLAGS.filter_channel])`
```

Comment: Are you asking how to count in each mini-batch while the training is going on ?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION :**

To count  how many outputs are greater than 0.5, just write the following line :

```
count = tf.count_nonzero(tf.greater(vector, 0.5))
```